# Why does it requires rules in lex?

Tags: yacc, lex

Like [this file](http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#JAXruTdKQ_g/trunk/development/lexer/smarty_internal_templatelexer.plex),in my opinion only declaration is enough.

Can anyone explain why rules are necessary in lexical analysis?

In my opinion they're only necessary in `.y` files...

By **rule** I'm talking about blocks like :

```
rdels {
  if ($this->smarty->auto_literal) {
     $this->token = Smarty_Internal_Templateparser::TP_OTHER;
  } else {
     $this->token = Smarty_Internal_Templateparser::TP_RDEL;
     $this->yypopstate();
  }
}
```

When to `yypopstate`,and `yypushstate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You enter **states**, when there can be ambiguous meanings to character input.

If the lexer encounters a `"` (quote), you might enter a state (`yypushstate`) called "string" in which any following character, which would otherwise have a special meaning (i.e. `+`, `-`, etc.) is considered part of the string. The "string" state is finished (`yypopstate`) when the lexer encounters another `"`.

In flex, these states are called [start conditions](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/flex/flex_11.html#SEC11).

Comment: If lex analysis also has states,then what's different from grammar analysis?

Comment: The lexical states only serve the purpose to differentiate input, not to define grammar. They cannot be reduced for instance.